# Passing Value in Modal Overlay, with Multiple Links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a value from a link to use in a modal overlay. if there's an easier or different way open to suggestions, but my attempt does not pass the value.  I want to pass the `data-id` through and place in text box.

```
link - data-toggle="modal"  href="#" title="Share" id=choose1 data-id="http://www.mylink" class="tip-box__head--share" data-reveal id="shareBetModal">
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="copy-block">
  <input type="text" value="" name="sharelink" readonly /> 
  <a href="#" class="button" title="Copy link">Copy link</a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
   $(document).on("click", ".tip-box__head--share", function () {
 var url = $(this).data('id');
 $(".copy-block #sharelink").val( url );
  });
```

The result is that it does not pass the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(".copy-block #sharelink").val( url );` - you don't have an element with `sharelink` id.

Try `$(".copy-block input[type=text]").val( url );` instead.

Also, your link seems malformed. Here's the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zyxdmncz/

Comment: Fiddle works fine in latest firefox. This is quite basic jQuery that should work on every browser.